# I'm not able to get data in drop-down from promise object, it showing data in console response. Angular Promise

Tags: angular, ngfor

[image]

component.ts file below:

```
deptList: Department[];
  ngOnInit() {

   this.service.getDeptList().then(res => this.deptList= 
    res as Department[]);
    this.resetForm();
 }
```

Service.ts below:

```
getDeptList(){
return this.http.get(environment.apiURL+'/dept/getAll').toPromise();
```

}
html file below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Department</label>
        <select  name="department" #department="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.department" 
               class="form-control">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option *ngFor="let dept of deptList" value="{{dept.id}}">{{dept.name}}</option>    
        </select>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: according to your second image,  where is the ``item`` in the HTML code?  could you please place the HTML file of the component?

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let itemlist of service.requestItemList; let i=index"></tr>
       <td>{{itemlist.item}}</td>
       <td>{{itemlist.code}}</td>
       <td>{{itemlist.requestedQty}}</td>
       <td>{{itemlist.rate}}</td>
       <td>{{itemlist.dateRequiredBy}}</td>
       <td>
        <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-white" (click)="AddOrEditOrderItem(null, service.formData.id)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
       </td>.export class MaterialRequsitionItems{
 id: number;
    item: string;
    code:string;
    requestedQty: number;
    dateRequiredBy: Date;
    rate: number;   
}

Comment: i guess there is no connection to item for department  drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, Your loop is as below :

```
<tr *ngFor="let itemlist of service.requestItemList; let i=index">
</tr>
<td>{{itemlist.item}}</td>
<td>{{itemlist.code}}</td>
<td>{{itemlist.requestedQty}}</td>
<td>{{itemlist.rate}}</td>
<td>{{itemlist.dateRequiredBy}}</td>
<td> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-white" (click)="AddOrEditOrderItem(null, service.formData.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
</td>
```

`cannot read property item of undefined`: this error is related to the above code, to solve you have to put all your `td` inside the `tr`

Modify your code like the following :

```
<tr *ngFor="let itemlist of service.requestItemList; let i=index">
    <td>{{itemlist.item}}</td>
    <td>{{itemlist.code}}</td>
    <td>{{itemlist.requestedQty}}</td>
    <td>{{itemlist.rate}}</td>
    <td>{{itemlist.dateRequiredBy}}</td>
    <td> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-white" (click)="AddOrEditOrderItem(null, service.formData.id)">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```